# R - How can I change date format when I plot an xts & zoo object?

Tags: r, plot, xts, quantmod, as.date

I am wondering how I can change date format.

The code I am working on is following:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL")
price_AAPL <- AAPL[,6]
plot(price_AAPL, main = "The price of AAPL")
```

This results

[image]

I want to alter date format from

```
"%m %d %Y"
```

as shown in the graphic to

```
"%b-%d-%Y"
```

So I tried following after searching some tips:

```
plot(price_AAPL, main = "The price of AAPL", xaxt="n")
axis.Date(1,
          at=seq(head(index(price_AAPL),1), 
                 tail(index(price_AAPL),1), length.out=5), 
          format="%b-%d-%Y", las=2)
```

But this doesn't help, and doesn't even show any labeling on x-axis. I suppose that I might did something wrong with "axis.Date()".

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `xts`, you can use `major.format` directly.

```
plot(price_AAPL, main = "The price of AAPL",major.format="%b-%d-%Y")
```

[image]

However, you should know that `zoo` plots are generally more flexible.

```
plot.zoo(price_AAPL, main = "The price of AAPL", xaxt="n", xlab="")
axis.Date(1,at=pretty(index(price_AAPL)),
            labels=format(pretty(index(price_AAPL)),format="%b-%d-%Y"),
            las=2, cex.axis=0.7)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I will take a look at "plot.zoo" more detail.

Comment: The parameter `major.format` passed into `plot.xts()` doesn't format the dates on the x-axis.  But the parameter `format.labels` does format the dates: 
`plot(price_AAPL, main="The price of AAPL", format.labels="%b-%d-%Y")`