# How to plot certain columns in R [xts]?

Tags: r, xts, zoo, graphing

I have a some data that looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjJ9k.jpg

And I am plotting it using:

```
plot(fifty_twoweekmovavg)
pdf("52_week_moving_average_chartNSW.pdf",onefile=TRUE)
addLegend("topleft",lty = 1,cex=1.2)
dev.off()
```

How do I plot it so that I only include a few variables?
E.g. plot the NSW price and coal price against time, rather than plotting every variable against time?

Thanks

Reproducible example:

`NSW1.Price Black.Coal      Gas     Hydro Liquid.Fuel
2011-01-01   30.89336   32.33668 41.63653  69.82661   108.06855
2011-01-08   30.98103   32.24805 41.33295  69.44308   104.36587
2011-01-15   30.73076   32.11497 40.76273  69.59129    97.30812
2011-01-22   30.76028   30.50381 36.56215  62.50329    61.78828
2011-01-29   29.76733   34.65090 43.94289  93.20954   113.42410`

Edit2, How I created data:

`mydata=read.csv(file="nem_tech_dataTAS.csv")
library(xts)
library(zoo)
date <- seq(from=as.POSIXct("2010-01-01 00:30", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), length.out = nrow(mydata), by = "30 min")
mydata_dated <- xts(mydata, date)
fifty_twoweekmovavg=rollapply(mydata_dated,17520,mean,by = 336,na.pad = FALSE)`

Edit3, format of legend:

Current legend:[image: legend1]

Desired legend: [image: legend2]

Comment: try using `ggplot` for plotting

Comment: `plot(fifty_twoweekmovavg$Gas,fifty_twoweekmovavg$Hydro)`

Comment: When I do this, it only plots the Gas data not the Hydro data as well?

Comment: Have you looked at the `lines` or `matplot` functions?

Comment: I have tried lines, but I can't get it to work with my legend? Could you help me out

Comment: `pdf` should be before `plot`. Also, take a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1), it will help us help you help us all.

Comment: Reproducible example in question now (I edited it).

Comment: Probably good to mention that the my data is an 'xts' object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotting xts objects can be done with the plot command if package `xts` has been loaded. For more details on how to plot xts objects, use `?plot.xts`.

To select only 2 columns you can use `grep` inside the xts object.

```
library(xts)

plot(fifty_twoweekmovavg[, grep("NSW1|Coal", names(fifty_twoweekmovavg))],
     legend(grep("NSW1|Coal", names(fifty_twoweekmovavg))),
     main = "52_week_moving_average",
     legend.loc = "topleft")
```

**edit:**
manipulating the legend, this makes it easier, and will result in the same plot, but with lines for the legend instead of squares:

```
plot(fifty_twoweekmovavg[, grep("NSW1|Coal", names(fifty_twoweekmovavg))],
     main = "52_week_moving_average")

# on = 1 is for main plot. lty is for showing a line in the legend.
# see ?addLegend and ?legend
addLegend("topleft", on = 1, lty=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Oh great, I’ll try this out

Comment: Works perfect thank you, although I don't completely understand how "grep" works

Comment: One minor thing but I'd like to fix it if I can is the format of the legend. Using your code my legend has a box indicating each colour, wheres originally I had a line indicating each colour. I have edited my question above to illustrate this. How do I format the legend with the line format rather than your box format? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to draw two lines that show the Gas and Hydro values over time, you first need to create a time series.  Create a column that gets the date and turns it into Date format using `as.Date`.  In your example above, you would write:

```
fifty_twoweekmovavg$date=as.Date(rownames(fifty_twoweekmovavg))
```

That gets you your x axis values.

Now in order to get both your Gas and Hydro values you have to make sure that the y axis fits both of them as the values for Gas and Hydro do not intersect.

One way of doing this is by:

```
extents=range(c(fifty_twoweekmovavg$Gas,fifty_twoweekmovavg$Hydro))
```

Once you have your date and extents set, you may finally proceed to plot your lines:

```
plot(fifty_twoweekmovavg$date,fifty_twoweekmovavg$Gas,type='l',ylim=extents)
lines(fifty_twoweekmovavg$date,fifty_twoweekmovavg$Hydro,col='red')
```

Comment: thanks but when I do your first line I get this:
`> fifty_twoweekmovavg$date=as.Date(rownames(fifty_twoweekmovavg))
Error in as.Date.default(x, ...) : 
  do not know how to convert 'x' to class “Date”`

Comment: Can you try `str(fifty_twoweekmovavg)` and copy and paste what you get.

Comment: `An ‘xts’ object on 2011-01-01/2018-12-29 containing:
  Data: num [1:418, 1:6] 30.9 30.9 30.7 30.6 30.6 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "TAS1.Price" "Gas" "Hydro" "Liquid.Fuel" ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: 
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL`

Comment: Ah, can you show the code you used to create the XTS object?  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429889/converting-an-xts-object-to-a-data-frame) may be useful to you.

Comment: yep its in the original question now

Comment: Try this: `fifty_twoweekmovavg_xts=fifty_twoweekmovavg` and then `fifty_twoweekmovavg=data.frame(date=index(fifty_twoweekmovavg),fifty_twoweekmovavg,row.names=NULL)`.  You will still have your old XTS object but this will allow you to plot in base using a data frame.  If you really want to plot the XTS object look into plot.zoo.  Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34319504/r-how-can-i-change-date-format-when-i-plot-an-xts-zoo-object).

Answer (score 0):

The code below can render a plot with multiple lines with the graph legend.

```
df2 = data.frame(matrix(data=c(
30.89336,   32.33668, 41.63653,  69.82661,   108.06855,
30.98103,   32.24805, 41.33295,  69.44308,   104.36587,
30.73076,   32.11497, 40.76273,  69.59129,    97.30812,
30.76028,   30.50381, 36.56215,  62.50329,    61.78828,
29.76733,   34.65090, 43.94289,  93.20954,   113.42410
), ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE ))
colnames(df2) = c("NSW1.Price", "Black.Coal", "Gas", "Hydro", "Liquid.Fuel")
df1 = data.frame("time" = as.Date(
      c("2011-01-01",   
        "2011-01-08",   
        "2011-01-15",   
        "2011-01-22",   
        "2011-01-29"),"%Y-%m-%d"))
df = cbind(df1, df2)
plot(0, cex=0, xlim=range(df$time), 
     ylim=c(0,max(c(df$NSW1.Price, df$Black.Coal))))
lines(df$time, df$NSW1.Price, col="cyan", lty = 1)
lines(df$time, df$Black.Coal, col="black", lty=2)
legend("bottomleft", legend = c("NSW1.Price", "Black.Coal"), 
       col = c("cyan", "black"), lty = c(1,2))
```

[image]